# Bad docker tag got daemon stuck

Tags: docker

I seem to have a container that is stuck in a bad state that I dont know how to get out of.

> $ docker ps -qa
>
> Error response from daemon: Error parsing reference:
>   "demoapp:feature/blue.background" is not a valid repository/tag

I think this offending container was created months ago. 
Is there any way I can delete it? I cant get a reference to it. Everything I try gives me the above error. Here is my info:

> $ docker version

```
Client:
 Version:      1.11.0
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.5.4
 Git commit:   4dc5990
 Built:        Wed Apr 13 18:38:59 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.11.0
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.5.4
 Git commit:   4dc5990
 Built:        Wed Apr 13 18:38:59 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

> $ docker info

```
Containers: 206
 Running: 1
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 205
Images: 1295
Server Version: 1.11.0
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 1834
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins: 
 Volume: local
 Network: host bridge null
Kernel Version: 4.4.0-22-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 8
Total Memory: 15.63 GiB
Name: digitus
ID: 5HUR:EIB6:FUJL:3WNH:CUSK:MXNT:QZB4:JKRA:NLGH:FX6X:GHS6:ONKT
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug mode (client): false
Debug mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: No swap limit support
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can (meaning if you don't have any local image or other running containers), you can try and:

- uninstall docker
- make sure `/var/lib/docker` is completely deleted ([there is actually a script for that](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/7423), but if the un-installation went well, you should not need it)
- re-install docker

That should take care of that corrupted entry.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping I would not have to go that far, but it ended up being too much of a pain to work around.